# Cannot find missing reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference

I am trying to copy code from one project to another.  There is one problem however:

```
The type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

The problem is that I can't find Microsoft.Practices.* anywhere.  Anyone know where I can find this file?

Comment: What version of .net are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to copy code from a *working* project, then that code must already have a reference to `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data`. Find the reference in Visual Studio and look at its properties.

Comment: I must really be doing something wrong.  I dont even see it listed in the other project :/

Comment: Check references in your project. If it id listed there, right click to see properties which should give you the path from where the assembly is referenced.

Comment: I did.  The only Microsoft references I saw were Microsoft.JScript  and Microsoft.Web.Preview.  Unless I am checking the references the wrong way (right clicking on the old project->Property Pages->References), I really dont know whats going on.

Comment: @0_o: For most projects I don't right-click, I just expand the "References" node... what sort of project is this, and what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: One of the projects was a web site.  With your comment about expanding the References node, I started looking at other nodes and found the library under the bin folder.  Everything works now :)

Answer (score 3):

you need to install [EnterpriseLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx).

From MSDN:

The Microsoft Enterprise Library is a collection of reusable software components (application blocks) designed to assist software developers with common enterprise development cross-cutting concerns (such as logging, validation, data access, exception handling, and many others). Application blocks are a type of guidance; they are provided as source code, test cases, and documentation that can be used "as is," extended, or modified by developers to use on complex, enterprise-level line-of-business development projects.

Answer (score 1):

See [**the 'Downloads' section here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650466.aspx) and choose "Enterprise Library 3.1  May 2007 (for .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.0)."

Comment: The thing is though, in the other project that this code was from, it works.  And its all on the same computer